# PKCS#11 Why i call C_GetSlotList return no slot with token presented for MacOS Application, and return one slot for Command Line Tool?

Tags: macos, smartcard, pkcs#11, hsm

I face some troubles about PKCS#11 library.
I create 2 projects:

- Project 1: macOS Application (GUI - with Objective-C)
- Project 2: Command line tool (Console - with C++)

```
unsigned long GetTokenInfos(CK_TOKEN_INFO_PTR pTokenInfo)
{
    CK_RV rv = CKR_OK;
    CK_ULONG ulCount = 0;
    CK_SLOT_ID_PTR pSlotList = NULL_PTR;

    rv = m_pToken->C_GetSlotList(TRUE, NULL_PTR, &ulCount);
    if(rv != CKR_OK){
        return rv;
    }
    if(ulCount <= 0){
        return CKR_TOKEN_NOT_PRESENT;
    }
    pSlotList = (CK_SLOT_ID_PTR)new CK_SLOT_ID [ulCount];
    rv = m_pToken->C_GetSlotList(TRUE, pSlotList, &ulCount);
    if((rv != CKR_OK) || (ulCount <= 0))
    {
        delete [] pSlotList;
        pSlotList = NULL_PTR;
        return CKR_TOKEN_NOT_PRESENT;
    }
    /*Get slot information for the first token*/
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ulCount; ++i)
    {
        rv = m_pToken->C_GetTokenInfo(pSlotList[i], pTokenInfo);
        if(rv != CKR_OK)
        {
            delete [] pSlotList;
            pSlotList = NULL_PTR;
            return rv;
        }
        //ShowTokenInfo(pTokenInfo);
    }
    delete [] pSlotList;
    pSlotList = NULL_PTR;
    return CKR_OK;
}
```

Both of them follow the same logic and flow of coding; build and run on a computer.
But I got a strange thing:
**Project macOS Application always return zero slot with HSM Token presented, on other side, project Command Line Tool always return one slot with token represented. **

I have no idea about the problem. I guess the macOS application project need some permissions or some things like that, in order to interact with hardware like HSM Token/ Smart Card...

Anyone had experience about the situation? Please give me some advice!
Thank you all!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do you follow double call convention described in section 5.5 of PKCS#11 standard?

Comment: Hi @Alexander,
Actually, At the first time i call C_GetSlotList (with tokenPresent = true), the function always return pulCount = 0 ...
So, it can not go to further ...!

Comment: It is recommended scenario when you first call C_GetSlotList with pSlotList = NULL and the second one with pointer to real storage for slot IDs.

Comment: Also refer to section 5.2 "Conventions for functions returning output in a variable-length buffer". C_GetSlotList meet this criteria.

Comment: Hi @Alexander. As i described, i call twice as you said,  but at the first time, the function return pulCount = 0 (with tokenPresent = TRUE), so  at the next time, the pSlotList (with pulCount = 0 <==> zero size) is unable to store any slot info pointer at all

Comment: Do you call to C_GetSlotList in both applications the same way - maybe some surrounding is taking an effect?? Please add [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code to question.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, i just add the get token info function to my question.
Please take a look and give me some other code if you had in order to do this case.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the same tool/IDE to build, run and debug both applications? I agree with your suggestion about application's permissions/security.

Comment: Yes, as i described, the GUI project use source files of command line project as a core library, and both of them are build-run on my computer (I have only one mac :))
So, it make me so confused!

Comment: Try to search inside of project's settings for security/permission issues.